# $first command is giving null values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the collection for "article_titles" and there are some title with repetitions involved in it. I want to pick the one that is earliest.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6375dbf89a70ce15b7c51172"), "title" : "Visualizing Graphs and Clusters as Maps", "year" : 2005, "name" : "amir" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6375dbf89a70ce15b7c5118a"), "title" : "Visualizing Dynamic Data with Maps", "year" : 2012, "name" : "amir" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6375dbf89a70ce15b7c511ac"), "title" : "Visualizing Cartograms: Goals and Task Taxonomy", "year" : 2015, "name" : "kobourov" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6375dbf99a70ce15b7c60293"), "title" : "Upward straight-line embeddings of directed graphs into point sets", "year" : 2008, "name" : "hossain" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6375dbf99a70ce15b7c738c7"), "title" : "Upward straight-line embeddings of directed graphs into point sets", "year" : 2010, "name" : "hossain" }
```

Here the name "hossain" has two same publications but in different years. I am trying to pick the first one,
I am using

```
db.article_titles.aggregate([{$sort:{year:-1}},{$group:{_id:{title:"$title",name:"$name",year:{$first:"$year"}}}}])
```

I want to understand what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What are your grouping fields? Is it by `title` and `kmapId` (which isn't in the sample documents)? `$first` is an accumulator, so it would usually be used in the `$group` but _not_ as part of the `_id` (the grouping values)

Comment: Sorry, it is a name, not kmapId, its name instead. I am grouping with ```name``` and ```title``` I tried this one too, ```db.article_titles.aggregate([{$sort:{year:-1}},{$group:{_id:{title:"$title",name:"$name"}}},{year:{$first:"$year"}}])```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Originally your `year: { $first: "$year" }` statement was nested too deeply (inside of `_id`). Then [with your second attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74524463/first-command-is-giving-null-values?noredirect=1#comment131554297_74524463) you pulled it out too far. It should be *inside* of `$group` but *outside* of `_id`:

```
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        title: "$title",
        name: "$name"
      },
      year: {
        $first: "$year"
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground demonstration here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fPc3hhzCSdn)